# Getting JSON array with Alamofire + SwiftyJSON

Tags: swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I'm really new to Swift, sorry if this is a dumb question... there seem to be many questions about this but none of them use the latest version of Alamofire

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, url)
    .responseJSON { response in

    let json = JSON(response.data!)
    debugPrint(json)
    self.delegate?.didReceiveAPIResults(json)
}
```

And the delegate's `didReceiveAPIResults` method

```
func didReceiveAPIResults(results: JSON) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.tableData = results["items"].arrayObject!
        self.appsTableView!.reloadData()
    })
}
```

Here's the JSON response:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Sample 1"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Sample 2"
        }
    ]
}
```

I expect the debugPrint to print something similar to that JSON, but instead it just prints `unknown`

If I debugPrint `response.data` by itself, it appears to be encoded...

```
Optional(<7b226461 7461223a 5b7b2269 64223a36 2c226e61 6d6522......
```

Then my `results["items"].arrayObject!` line has this error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than grabbing `response.data`, I'd suggest grabbing `response.result.value`. When you do `responseJSON`, Alamofire does the JSON parsing for you, and you should feel free to just grab this parsed object.

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, url)
    .responseJSON { response in
        if let value = response.result.value {
            let json = JSON(value)
            self.delegate?.didReceiveAPIResults(json)
        }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks. And now I see `response.result.value` pretty clearly in the Alamofire documentation, I just missed that somehow